# php - функции, аргументы

Tags: php

Всем привет. Вопрос по PHP. Параметры указываются в определении функции, внутри круглых скобок, и являются ее локальными переменными, т.е. они видны только в ее теле, если параметров несколько, то они указываются через запятую. 
Но в примере параметр $color указываются вне функции. Объясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```
 <?php
 
  // Определение функции
  function my_car($car, $color) {  // Указано два параметра: $car и $color
    echo "Марка моей машины: $car и она имеет $color цвет";
  }
  
  $color = 'красный';

  

  // Вызываем функцию и передаем ей два аргумента
  my_car('BMW', $color);  // Аргументы - строковой литерал и переменная
 
?>
```

Comment: это две разные переменные: та что в теле - локальная, а та что за пределами тела функции - глобальная. Общее у них только имя.

Comment: вне функции указывается переменная `$color`, которая не имеет отношение к самой функции. Затем она передается в эту функцию, как одноименный параметр по значению

Comment: а почему тогда ее нельзя  в теле функции прописать, чтобы она так же работала? Если что я  новичок, поэтому не судите строго.

Comment: @juice11 можно её прописать и в теле функции, и за телом функции - но это будут разные переменные, с одинаковыми именами. Проще будет сказать, что у этих одноименных переменных `разная область видимости`, как если бы вы назвали одинаково два текст.файла, которые находятся в разных папках.

Comment: отличное объяснение, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Просто переменную вне функции и внутри функции назвали одинаково. Но это абсолютно разные переменные. С таким же успехом можно было просто написать:

```
function my_car($car, $color) { 
    echo "Марка моей машины: $car и она имеет $color цвет";
}

$this_is_my_var_with_some_value = 'красный';
my_car('BMW', $this_is_my_var_with_some_value);
```

Comment: спасибо. все понятно

Answer (score 1):

Вы все правильно начали, `Определение функции`.
Так вот, для определения используется зарезервированное слово `function` далее идет `название_ функции` и `прототип функции (где перечисляются параметры, через запятую)`, а дальше следует тело функции `{}`, где будут видны эти переменные.
То, что переменная `$color` определена вне функции - эту переменную, функция не видит, хоть переменная и находится в глобальной области видимости.
Функция имеет локальную область видимости.
Для того, чтобы функция увидела переменную, вы ее и передаете в прототип функции:

```
my_car('BMW', $color);
```

Есть еще конструкция `global` - которая приглашает переменную в локальную область видимости функции.

```
$color = 'red';
function my_car() {
    global $color;
    return $color;
}
echo my_car(); // red
```

Конечно не рекомендую использовать эту конструкцию.

В вашем случае может еще появиться переменная `$car` - которая также будет передаваться в прототип функции.

```
$car = 'BMW';
$color = 'black';
my_car($car, $color);
```

Примерно такое-же происходит и с ООП:

```
class Car {
    public $car, $color;
    public function __construct($car, $color) {
       $this->car = $car;
       $this->color = $color;
    }
}
```